# How to fix mystery padding gap between html elements?

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a paragraph element followed by an unordered list (the ul comes from the Simple Image Gallery extension for Joomla), and there is a vertical gap of about 200px between the two that I cannot explain at all! The gap appears in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Even using the DOM viewer in firebug or Chrome's developer tools, there is absolutely no padding or margin values in the CSS being applied that should cause this gap - it's a real mystery!

I have already put * {margin:0, padding:0} in place with no luck. I get the feeling it has something to do with the webkit-padding values being added by the browser or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `clear:none;` on `#main ul.sig-container`

`clear:both` makes it appear vertically on a new line after the floats above it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! That worked perfectly! Such a simple fix after spending so long trying to work it out... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by add css rule to your stylesheet

```
#wrapper {
    float: right;
}
```